UI is not updating the index in Angular child component when trying to change it from the parent component. What am I missing?
I'm trying to update the page index from the parent component in an Angular application using a child component that handles pagination. The child component has an index input property and an event emitter for page changes. However, when I try to update the index from the parent, the UI does not reflect the updated value, and the pagination does not change.My project is on Angular 13.
    import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'numbered-pagination',
  templateUrl: './numbered-pagination.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./numbered-pagination.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class NumberedPaginationComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() index: number = 1;
  @Input() totalCount: number = 0;
  @Input() pageSize: number = 50;
  @Input() rulerLength: number = 5;

  @Output() page: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  maxPages: number = 1;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes['totalCount'] || changes['pageSize']) {
      this.calculateMaxPages();
    }
  }

  private calculateMaxPages(): void {
    this.maxPages = Math.ceil(this.totalCount / this.pageSize) || 1;
  }

  get pagination(): NumberedPagination {
    const { index, maxPages, rulerLength } = this;
    const pages = ruler(index, maxPages, rulerLength);
    return { index, maxPages, pages };
  }

  navigateToPage(pageNumber: number): void {
    if (allowNavigation(pageNumber, this.index, this.maxPages)) {
      this.index = pageNumber;
      this.page.emit(this.index);
      console.log("Index  =>> " + this.index);
    }
    console.log("Index1  =>> " + this.index);
  }

  trackByFn(index: number): number {
    return index;
  }

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  refreshToInitial() {
    this.navigateToPage(1);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
  }
}


function generatePageArray(rulerLength: number): number[] {
  const result: number[] = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= rulerLength; i++) {
    result.push(i);
  }
  return result;
}
const ruler = (
  currentIndex: number,
  maxPages: number,
  rulerLength: number
): number[] => {
  if (maxPages <=rulerLength) {
    return generatePageArray(maxPages);; // If maxPages is 1, return an array with only 1 page
  }
  const array = new Array(rulerLength).fill(null);
  const min = Math.floor(rulerLength / 2);

  return array.map((_, index) =>
    rulerFactory(currentIndex, index, min, maxPages, rulerLength)
  );
};

const rulerOption = (
  currentIndex: number,
  min: number,
  maxPages: number
): RulerFactoryOption => {
  return currentIndex <= min
    ? RulerFactoryOption.Start
    : currentIndex >= maxPages - min
    ? RulerFactoryOption.End
    : RulerFactoryOption.Default;
};

const rulerFactory = (
  currentIndex: number,
  index: number,
  min: number,
  maxPages: number,
  rulerLength: number
): number => {
  const factory = {
    [RulerFactoryOption.Start]: () => index + 1,
    [RulerFactoryOption.End]: () => maxPages - rulerLength + index + 1,
    [RulerFactoryOption.Default]: () => currentIndex + index - min,
  };

  return factory[rulerOption(currentIndex, min, maxPages)]();
};

const allowNavigation = (
  pageNumber: number,
  index: number,
  maxPages: number
): boolean => {
  return pageNumber !== index && pageNumber > 0 && pageNumber <= maxPages;
};

HTML part of Child Component
<ol *ngIf="maxPages>1" class="paginator-container">
  <li (click)="navigateToPage(1)">
    <i matTooltip="First Page" class="fa-solid fa-angles-left"></i>&nbsp;
      <span>First</span>
  </li>
  <li (click)="navigateToPage(index - 1)"><i matTooltip="Previous Page" class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>&nbsp;<span>Previous</span></li>
  <li
    *ngFor="let page of pagination.pages; trackBy: trackByFn"
    class="paginator-number"
    [class.active]="page === pagination.index"
    (click)="navigateToPage(page)"
    
    >
    {{ page }}
  </li>
  <li (click)="navigateToPage(index + 1)"><span>Next</span>&nbsp;<i matTooltip="Next Page" class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i></li>
  <li (click)="navigateToPage(maxPages)">
    <span>Last</span>&nbsp;
    <i matTooltip="Last Page" class="fa-solid fa-angles-right"></i>
</li>
</ol>

Parent Component TypeScript
<button class="edit_button" (click)="onAssignToButtonClick('Extracted')">
  Assign To
</button>

<numbered-pagination [index]="extractedPageNumber" (page)="pageEvent('New', $event)" [pageSize]="pageSize" [totalCount]="pageNumberExtractedLimit"></numbered-pagination>

Problem:

I'm trying to update the page index from the parent component using
the refreshPaginationToInitial method, but the child component's
pagination UI doesn't reflect the updated index.
The child component uses ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and is not
updating the UI when the index value changes in the parent.

What I've tried:

I’m using ChangeDetectorRef in the child component to manually
trigger change detection, but it doesn’t seem to update the UI.

The child’s pagination logic correctly emits page changes via the
page output, but the UI doesn't react to the changes.


Can someone explain why this isn't working or suggest a solution?

Why are you not using @Input() page: number = 1; and @Output() pageChange = new EventEmitter<number>();? This allows you to use the banana-in-the-box notation ([(page)]="pageValue")

Maybe you can provide a stackblitz example so we could see the whole implementation including the template of the child component.

As far as I can see, your usage of ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush is making the change detection scenario too narrow and it's not catching the changes you'd expect. My suggestion is to remove that (no changeDetection at all), OR redo your operations on variables, but I cannot be certain what to do there since child's ts/html is not provided and I don't see how you actually handle the value. Take a look at https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/

Apologies for the oversight, I realized I didn't include the HTML part of the pagination component. I'll provide that now

I want to know the reason why console is showing correct value of index which is inside navigateToPage function but html UI part is not reflecting the change

Thanks to Pieterjan’s reply, I tried implementing two-way binding. However, to fix the issue, I had to create a new component with the same logic. Here’s the change I made :
  @Output() page: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

With this:
  @Output() indexChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

Despite this change, it didn’t work in the old component, and I had to create a new pagination component.
I’m not sure why this change didn’t take effect in the existing component. Does anyone know why this might happen?
